# Standard Category of Components gone walkabout

Tags: windows, delphi

Somehow I managed to delete the Standard category of components from my RIO IDE.
How do I recover from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you did.

Deleted the palette category? Right click in the palette area and select "Reset Palette".

Unselected the standard components package? Component menu, install packages. In the list make sure the Embarcadero Standard Components package is selected.

Deleted random files in the install directory? Reinstall Delphi.

Started a command line project? There are no standard components for this type of project.

Comment: The Reset Palette fixed the problem. As many years that I have been using Delphi (Turbo Pascal), I never knew that option was available.